# ¿Como puedo mostrar los tres (solo tres) empleados que ganan más dinero del departamento Shipping en SQL 11g Express?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

Hola necesito ayuda para mostrar los 3 empleados los cuales están en la tabla de EMPLOYEES y su SALARIO en el usuario HR de ORACLE 11g express y no me esta funcionando esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT TOP 3 FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, MAX(SALARY)
FROM EMPLOYEES E
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D ON (E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID)
INNER JOIN JOBS J ON
(E.JOB_ID = J.JOB_ID)
ORDER BY SALARY desc;
```

Pido perdón por no haber escrito las tablas aquí pero cuando las puse se veía muy feo y por mas que intente ponerlas como deberían estar no se mostró como en la imagen.

Comment: Al parecer la tabla `JOBS` sólo muestra rangos de sueldo. Te falta mostrarnos la tabla HR creo yo.  Pero si el SALARY está en la tabla EMPLOYEES no necesitas hacer joins, sólo despliega el SALARY y ordena por SALARY DESC

Comment: @amenadiel: `HR` es un schema estándar de Oracle con datos de prueba para practicar consultas. La descripción de las tablas en ese schema se pueden ver aquí: https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/COMSC/HR-sample-schema-table-descriptions.htm#COMSC00021.

Comment: @sstan lol, yo pensé que era Human Resources. Buen dato el que me das! Gracias!

Comment: @amenadiel: En realidad, pensastes bien. Es un schema de ejemplo con tablas que simulan los datos necesarios para una aplicación Human Resources :)

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Como puedo mostrar los tres (solo tres) empleados que ganan más dinero del departamento Shipping en SQL 11g Express?

1. Oracle no usa el keyword `TOP`. En Oracle 11 necesitas usar `rownum`.
2. No necesitas el join con la tabla `jobs` para encontrar los empleados que trabajan en el departamento `Shipping`. Solo necesitas un join con `departments`

Consulta usando `rownum`:

```
select *
  from (select e.* 
          from employees e
          join departments d
            on d.department_id = e.department_id
           and d.department_name = 'Shipping'
         order by e.salary desc)
where rownum <= 3
```

Comment: Me funciono gracias sstan *_*

Comment: Entendi casi toda tu consulta pero, tengo una sola duda cuando pusiste (select e.* from employees e............ porque le pusiste ese "e.*'

Comment: ¿Estás hablando del `e.*`, o del `employees e`?

Comment: Del e.* nunca habia visto eso, ni tampoco he visto que mi profesor haga algo similar.

Comment: Osea yo entiendo que dentro de un select se ponen las columnas que uno desea mostrar, pero no entiendo que función cumple eso ahi.

Comment: Es para que solo devuelva los datos de la tabla `employees`. Si hiciera `*`, entonces devolvería las columnas de ambas tablas (`employees` + `departments`)

Comment: Ahh ok, entonces deben ser tecnisismos, metodos mas de expertos seguro con el tiempo ya aprendere a hacer metodos de ese tipo gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema está en usar `MAX(Salary)`... No deberías usar la función `MAX()` en este caso.

La consulta debería ser:

```
SELECT TOP 3 FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY
FROM EMPLOYEES
JOIN ...
ORDER BY SALARY DESC;
```

Comment: Es que se me paso por la mente que tendria que usar MAX() por el hecho de que mostrar los que mas ganan dinero pero ahora que lo mencionas creo que me tengo que replantear mejor la preguntas, gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Seria bueno que muestres que es lo que te devuelve esa consulta pero hasta donde entiendo, oracle lo que hace es primero separarte las 3 resultados top (creo q mejor seria usar "where rownum <=3") y despues ordena esas 3, lo que puedes hacer es una subconsulta:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM empleados ORDER BY sueldo) WHERE rownum <= 3;
```